# Need HTML characters stripped out of excel export, but effects preserved

Tags: html, excel, coldfusion, html-parsing

I'm exporting data using CF9's cfspreeadsheet tags and functions, some columns have HTML formatted text in them. I need to strip out the HTML tags, and convert characters like &lt and &amp to their equivalents. However, I'd also like to keep the effects of bold tags and paragraphs tags if possible.

I know I can use rereplace, and others to brute force the output, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just had to do something similar so I just wrote a macro for a find/replace on anything that I came across that could cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to strip out the HTML tags, and convert characters like &lt and
>   &amp to their equivalents. However,
>   I'd also like to keep the effects of
>   bold tags and paragraphs tags if
>   possible.
>
> I know I can use rereplace, and others
>   to brute force the output, but I was
>   hoping for a more elegant solution.

I do not think such a function exists in CF. It would require some sort of html=>excel conversion of the styles. [This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@poi.apache.org/msg05241.html) says that functionality did not even exist in POI (which is used by cfspreadsheet) until recently. So my guess would be it does not exist within the CF spreadsheet functions either.

If you are willing to work lower level, you might check the latest version of [POI](http://poi.apache.org/). See if the [mentioned patch](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@poi.apache.org/msg05249.html) is available in the main distribution. Otherwise, rereplace() sounds like the simplest approach.